# Suggestion for this kind of execution in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, timeout, execution

I have a web application that sends a single sms to multiple numbers via gsm.Every user has this application in his local system. I am able to send messages one by one. Thus far i have only 10 numbers so there is no problem. Consider i have a file having 10000 mobile numbers,

- what will happen to my execution
  time?
- What is your suggestion for this scenario?

**NOTE:**
I dont use an sms gateway because its a simple application which ll be hosted in IIS of my user system only..

I have mobile phone connected to my system and i am sending sms through it..

Comment: One phone can only send one sms at any time, to my knowledge, so then it doesn't matter what you do, your phone is the bottleneck. Third party sms packages are so cheap these days, and guaranteed to be quicker, why dont you consider those?

Comment: @Ryk can you suggest me a third party sms package

Comment: Try this --> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=email+to+sms&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your execution time will grow edit:(linearly).

Why dont you use windows queuing and then write every sms to the queue and then have a windows service running spinning up 1 - n number of threads to send sms's, but I guess the biggest problem for you will not be what your code limits you to do, but how many sms's you can send simultaneously with your gsm.

Comment: It'll grow linearly, not exponentially... but otherwise your idea is a good one.

Comment: why exponentially?  I can see linear growth.

Comment: Sorry, English is my third language, had a few things mixed up in my head.